# Angular 5 Property 'username' does not exist on type 'string[]'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to make a simple edit component. From a Javascript view, I can't see anything wrong, but I think I'm not working with a scope the way Angular wants, so I'm looking for some guidance. `ERROR in src\app\admin\customers\customer-edit\customer-edit.component.html(10,97): : Property 'username' does not exist on type 'string[]'.`

**customer-edit.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ToasterService, ToasterConfig } from 'angular2-toaster';
import { AdminService } from '../../admin.service';
import { customer } from '../../../../environments/environment';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-admin/customer/edit-list',
    templateUrl: './customer-edit.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./customer-edit.component.scss']
})

export class CustomerEditComponent implements OnInit {

    editCustomerForm: FormGroup;
    toaster: any;
    data: string[];
    toasterConfig: any;
    toasterconfig: ToasterConfig = new ToasterConfig({
        positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right',
        showCloseButton: true
    });

    constructor(
        private adminService: AdminService,
        private toasterService: ToasterService,
        private router: Router
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getProfile();
    }

    getProfile() {
        let dataCustomer = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
        this.data = dataCustomer as string[];
    }

    updateProfile(data) {
        let dataSelect = {
            id: data.id,
            email: ((document.getElementById("txt_newEmail") as HTMLInputElement).value),
            mobile: ((document.getElementById("txt_newMobileNumber") as HTMLInputElement).value),
            password: ((document.getElementById("txt_newPassowrd") as HTMLInputElement).value),
        }
        this.adminService.add<any>(customer.customerUpdate, dataSelect).subscribe(res => {
            this.toasterService.pop('success', 'Success', res.message);
        }, error => {
            this.toasterService.pop('error', 'Error', error.error.message);
        });
    }

    navigateCancle() {
        this.router.navigate(['admin/customers/list']);
    }
}
```

My Html code is 
**customer-edit.component.html**

```
<legend style="align-content:center">Edit Customer</legend>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
         <form class="text-center border border-light p-5">
                <div class="row col-md-12">
                            <label class="col-md-4" style="text-align:right;font-size:20px">Username</label>
                            <label class="col-md-6 mb-4" style="text-align:left;font-size:20px">{{data.username}}</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row col-md-12">
                            <button class="btn btn-info col-md-4" type="submit" (click)="updateProfile(data)">Update</button>
                            <div class="col-1"></div>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger col-md-4" type="submit" (click)="navigateCancle()" >Cancle</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

**What is expected?**

I don't know if it's because of my writing, or because of the configuration that caused me this error. I wrote the code based on the official document. I believe it can be built successfully.

**What is actually happening?**

When I run npm run build, The complete prompt is as follows:

> 1>ERROR in
>   src\app\admin\customers\customer-edit\customer-edit.component.html(10,97):
>   : Property 'username' does not exist on type 'string[]'.

Thanks.

Comment: Can we know what did you store on your localStorage ?

Comment: @KShewengger Yes sure, Json data string.

Comment: Well you have string array, and you are trying to use as object. Try this one : data[0].username instead of data.username. Or change `data : string[]` to `data : any;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have declared `data` as `string[]` string array, but it should be of `any` type and you are accessing the property of that `data` as `data.userName`

Also you need to parse string `JSON.parse`

Answer (score 9):

declare 'data' variable as

```
data:any;
```

it will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and resolved the issue by importing Response,
import { Http,Response } from '@angular/Http';